# Question about difference between two phrases

Tags: grammar

I need help.
Is "battery charging efficiency" phrase grammatically correct?
If yes, what is difference between "battery charging efficiency" and "battery charge efficiency" ?

Comment: It would be easier to answer this question if you used a complete sentence.  It's difficult to say if a single phrase is grammatically correct, because the correctness might depend on the other words that are around it.

Answer (score 1):

"*Charging*" is the process by which a battery is charged.

Although "*charge*" can be used as a verb to describe the process (ie *to charge a battery*) it can just mean the level of power that is currently *held* by a battery (eg *there isn't much charge left in this battery*).

If you say "*battery charging efficiency*" it sounds like you are referring to the efficiency of the charging *process*; ie does the battery take 30 minutes to charge, or does it take 60 minutes to charge.

To be honest, "*battery charge efficiency*" is a bit vague, but I suppose it *could* be taken to mean the efficiency of the battery, ie how long it lasts in use.

The true opposite of charging is *discharging*, but you wouldn't really use that word to describe *efficiency* of a battery because a truly efficient battery wouldn't discharge, it would *hold* its charge for as long as possible.

If you want to refer to the charging process, use *charging*. Otherwise, better terms for describing the *use* of a battery might be:

- Battery efficiency
- Battery *life*
- Battery *usage*